# Three.js How to use your structure in shaders?

Tags: three.js, shader

I am writing a shader and I need to somehow transfer the parameters to it.
In the code I found some structure, but I do not understand how it works.

```
struct Light {
    vec4 position;
    vec4 ambient;
    vec4 diffuse;
    vec4 specular;
    vec3 spotDirection;
    float spotCutOff;
    float constantAttenuation;
    float linearAttenuation;
    float quadraticAttenuation;
    float spotExponent;
    float spotLightCosCutOff;
};
uniform Light lights[numLights];
```

How can I set my structure in my shader?

Comment: Similar to a question I asked a while ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38833195/shaders-structs For an array of structures, it's literally as simple as setting the uniform to an array of objects.

Comment: Something I tried to do, but something still does not work out, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/546syLur/13/ (there must be a white square)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each field of each item of the `Light` array'll be a separate uniform:

```
gl.uniform4f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'lights[0].position'), 1, 1, 1, 1);
gl.uniform1f(gl.getUniformLocation(program, 'lights[3].spotCutOff'), 3);
```

@TheJim01 has pointed out that your question is Three.js specific (thanks:). There the same principle stands:

```
yourShaderMaterial.uniforms['lights[0].spotCutOff'].value = 3;
```

Comment: This is good for raw WebGL, but the question involves THREE.js, which obfuscates the gl calls through easier-to-use function calls and properties.

Comment: @TheJim01 I've amended the answer:)

Comment: Something I tried to do, but something still does not work out, here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/546syLur/13/ (there must be a white square)

Comment: @user2783211 I made some changes to your code. Notice that you don't need to use the string-ified name to set the value. Just set the value to an array of objects with the correct structure properties. http://jsfiddle.net/TheJim01/546syLur/14/